# Angular16 http client post with response as string (text)

Tags: rest, post, httpclient, angular16

I'm trying to make a http post request to my backend that returns only a string with the token (if user logged in succesfully). I've read the angular documentation and it is clearly reported that there is a post method that does my job:

```
Overload #3
Constructs a POST request that interprets the body as a text string and returns the response as a string value.
post(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; context?: HttpContext; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | number | boolean | readonly (string | ... 1 more ... | boolean)[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType: "text"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<string>
```

From the docs it seems I need to insert the 'responseType' key in the options object so I wrote the following function:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<string> {
    
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'username': username,
        'password': password
      }),
      responseType: 'text'
    }
    return this.http.post<string>('https://testlogin.it/v1/login', null, options);
    
  }
```

But a lot of errors come out:

```
Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

and

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 15, '(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
      Property 'observe' is missing in type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' but required in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.

....omissis...
```

I also searched everywhere in internet but noone has my problem. Any idea on what is wrong?

Thanks